# Break up the data in a database column of a record into multiple records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Azure SQL Server - we have a table like this:

**MyTable**:

```
ID    Source     ArticleText
--    ------     -----------
1     100        <nvarchar(max) field with unstructured text from media articles>
2     145        "
3     866        "
4     232        "
```

`ID` column is the primary key and auto-increments on `INSERTS`.

I run this query to find the records with the largest data size in the `ArticleText` column:

```
SELECT TOP 500 
    ID, Source, DATALENGTH(ArticleText)/1048576 AS Size_in_MB
FROM 
    MyTable
ORDER BY 
    DATALENGTH(ArticleText) DESC
```

We are finding that for many reasons both technical and practical, the data in the `ArticleText` column is just too big in certain records. The above query allows me to look at a range of sizes for our largest records, which I'll need to know for what I'm trying to formulate here.

The feat I need to accomplish is, for all existing records in this table, any record whose `ArticleText` `DATALENGTH` is greater than X, break that record into X amount of records where each record will then contain the same value in the `Source` column, but have the data in the `ArticleText` column split up across those records in smaller chunks.

How would one achieve this if the exact requirement was say, take all records whose `ArticleText` `DATALENGTH` is greater than 10MB, and break each into 3 records where the resulting records' `Source` column value is the same across the 3 records, but the `ArticleText` data is separated into three chunks.

In essence, we would need to divide the `DATALENGTH` by 3 and apply the first 1/3 of the text data to the first record, 2nd 1/3 to the 2nd record, and the 3rd 1/3 to the third record.

Is this even possible in SQL Server?

Comment: So you don't care about breaking on word boundaries? Do you plan on adding a column to store the order of the `ArticleText` segments or don't you care about reassembling them in any particular order?

Comment: @HABO that's a great point about breaking work boundaries.  We wouldn't care about a sentence being split up, but we'd certainly not want any words being split.  The order of the resulting records does not matter.

Comment: Try starting with a recursive CTE that uses [`CharIndex()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to find a space after some starting position, e.g. `CharIndex( ' ', ArticleText, 9999990 )`, splitting the string at the blank and repeating until the string is consumed. It's not perfect since it doesn't recognize punctuation, other whitespace, ..., but it's a start. (And don't let those pesky thirds of a character keep you up at night.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to create a side table with the needed data:

```
CREATE TABLE #mockup (ID INT IDENTITY, [Source] INT, ArticleText NVARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO #mockup([Source],ArticleText) VALUES
 (100,'This is a very long text with many many words and it is still longer and longer and longer, and even longer and longer and longer')
,(200,'A short text')
,(300,'A medium text, just long enough to need a second part');

DECLARE @partSize INT=50;

WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT ID,[Source]
          ,1 AS FragmentIndex
          ,A.Pos
          ,CASE WHEN A.Pos>0 THEN LEFT(ArticleText,A.Pos) ELSE ArticleText END AS Fragment
          ,CASE WHEN A.Pos>0 THEN SUBSTRING(ArticleText,A.Pos+2,DATALENGTH(ArticleText)/2) END AS RestString
    FROM #mockup
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT CASE WHEN DATALENGTH(ArticleText)/2 > @partSize 
                            THEN @partSize - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(LEFT(ArticleText,@partSize)))
                            ELSE -1 END AS Pos) A

    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.ID,r.[Source]
         ,r.FragmentIndex+1
         ,A.Pos
         ,CASE WHEN A.Pos>0 THEN LEFT(r.RestString,A.Pos) ELSE r.RestString END
         ,CASE WHEN A.Pos>0 THEN SUBSTRING(r.RestString,A.Pos+2,DATALENGTH(r.RestString)/2) END AS RestString
    FROM recCTE r
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT CASE WHEN DATALENGTH(r.RestString)/2 > @partSize 
                            THEN @partSize - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(LEFT(r.RestString,@partSize)))
                            ELSE -1 END AS Pos) A
    WHERE DATALENGTH(r.RestString)>0
)
SELECT ID,[Source],FragmentIndex,Fragment 
FROM recCTE
ORDER BY [Source],FragmentIndex;

GO
DROP TABLE #mockup
```

The result

```
+----+--------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| ID | Source | FragmentIndex | Fragment                                          |
+----+--------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | 100    | 1             | This is a very long text with many many words and |
+----+--------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | 100    | 2             | it is still longer and longer and longer, and     |
+----+--------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | 100    | 3             | even longer and longer and longer                 |
+----+--------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| 2  | 200    | 1             | A short text                                      |
+----+--------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| 3  | 300    | 1             | A medium text, just long enough to need a second  |
+----+--------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| 3  | 300    | 2             | part                                              |
+----+--------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Now you have to update the existing line with the value at `FragmentIndex=1`, while you have to insert the values of `FragmentIndex>1`. Do this sorted by FragmentIndex and your `IDENTITY` ID-column will reflect the correct order.

Comment: Will try this tomorrow and revert with any questions/issues.  Thanks Shnugo!